# How to modify dynamic complex data type fields in azure data factory data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a complex data type (fraudData) that undesirably has hyphen characters in the field names I need to remove or change the hypens to some other character.

The input schema of the complex object looks like:
[image]

I have tried using the "**Select**" and "**Derive Column**" data flow functions and adding a custom mapping. It seems both functions have the same mapping interface. My current attempt with **Select** is:
[image]

This gets me close to the desired results. I can use the `replace` expression to convert hypens to underscores.

The problem here is that this mapping creates new root level columns outside of the `fraudData` structure. I would like to preserve the hierarchy of the `fraudData` structure and modify the column names in place.

If I am unable to modify the `fraudData` in place. Is there any way I can take the new columns and merge them into another complex data type?

**Update:**. I do not know the fields of the complex data type in advance. This is a schema drift problem. This is why I have tried using the pattern matching solution. I will not be able to hardcode out kown sub-column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the sub-columns of complex data type using derived column transformation and convert them as a complex data type again. I tried this with sample data and below is the approach.

- Sample complex data type column with two sub fields are taken as in below image.
  [image]
  img:1 source data preview
- In Derived column transformation, For the column `fraudData`, expression is given as

```
@(fraudData_1_chn=fraudData.{fraudData-1-chn},
fraudData_2_chn=fraudData.{fraudData-2-chn})
```

[image]
img:2 Derived column settings

- This expression renames the subfields and nests them under the parent column `fraudData`.

[image]
img:3 Transformed data- Fields are renamed.

**Update: To rename sub columns dynamically**

- You can use below expression to rename all the fields under the root column `fraudData`.

```
@(each(fraudData, match(true()), replace($$,'-','_') =  $$))
```

[image]

This will replace fields which has `-` with `_`.

[image: gif112]

You can also use pattern match in the expression.

```
@(each(fraudData, patternMatch(`fraudData-.+` ), replace($$,'-','_') = $$))
```

This expression will take fields with pattern `fraudData-.+` and replace `-` with `_` in those fields only.

***Reference:***

1. **Microsoft document** on [script for hierarchical definition in data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#sample-manual-script-for-complete-hierarchical-definition).
2. **Microsoft document** on [building schemas using derived column transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column#building-schemas-using-the-expression-builder) .

Comment: This solution appears to be for a kown static list of subcolums on the complex data type. I do not know the column names in advance. I will not preemptively be able to hardcode out the column names

Comment: You can use this expression in derived column transformation to replace `-` with `_`. `@(each(fraudData, match(true()), replace($$,'-','_') =  $$))`.

Comment: Where exactly is that script supposed to be added? I have added it to the `Derived Column settings` it does not have the desired results. It create a new column and does not modify the existing `fraudData`

Comment: In derived column transformation, you can either create a new column or update the existing column. If you give column name as `fraudData` and expression `@(each(fraudData, match(true()), replace($$,'-','_') =  $$))` , this will replace the old `fraudData` with the new expression.

Comment: Do you still have any error in modifying column name?

Comment: This answer is very helpful for a different problem that I'm having, but where is the documentation on the "each" function?  I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Check the second link in the reference section of my answer.